# _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince suddenly reports 700 allocations after one call to realloc

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, memory-leaks, crt

I suspect I have some memory leaks problem so I defined two functions that I can call from the immediate window while stepping through my code:

```
_CrtMemState s1;

void SetMemCheckPoint() {
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&s1);
}

void CompareMemory() {
    _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&s1);
}
```

Then I have this line somewhere:

```
buf = (char*)realloc(buf, (strlen(src)+1)*sizeof(char)); //yes I'm aware sizeof(char) = 1
//Don't worry, after this, if (!buf) I fast fail and exit(-1)
```

Just before stepping through this line, calling `SetMemCheckPoint()` then `CompareMemory()` in the immediate window reports no new allocations (as it obviously should).

Then, just after stepping through this line, calling `CompareMemory()` in the immediate window reports this:

```
Dumping objects ->
{6886} normal block at 0x19941B90, 58 bytes long.
 Data: <C:\Users\XXXXXXX> 43 3A 5C 55 73 65 72 73 5C XX XX XX XX XX XX XX
{3974} client block at 0x1921D600, subtype 0, 10 bytes long.
 Data: <% /m K    > 25 00 2F 6D 00 4B 00 CD CD CD 
{3807} client block at 0x05D45800, subtype 0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <r               > 72 0B CB 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
```

[... 700 more allocations ...]

```
{153} client block at 0x05D5BF90, subtype 0, 11 bytes long.
 Data: <log.log    > 6C 6F 67 2E 6C 6F 67 00 CD CD CD 
{152} client block at 0x05BD5C00, subtype 0, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 90 BF D5 05 08 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD 
{151} client block at 0x05C5B210, subtype 0, 32 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E8 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

All these allocations seems to be memory allocated *before* calling `SetMemCheckPoint()`.

Is MS crt `realloc()` somehow messing with the (MS) crt debug heap and corrupting my checkpoint s1?

Or am I missing something ?

### edit

This code is in a dll called from Excel macros (vba). Maybe there are some strange interactions between Excel and my debug-compiled dll (that is itself dynamically linked to msvcr120d.dll).

Also, the realloc call does return a new pointer, but subsequent calls seem to "cycle" between a few addresses. I am wondering if this causes `_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince` to see this "new" pointer as an "old" allocation, and then dump all allocations since this "old" one ?

I can't reproduce it in a minimal program :( It seems it has something to do with interactions between my dll and Excel/3rd party code indeed...

Comment: seeing the rest of the code would greatly help the debug process.   However, when calling realloc() always 1) place the result in a temp pointer then check that temp pointer (!=NULL) before copying the temp pointer to 'buf'.   Not using a temp pointer will result in the original pointer being set to NULL, resulting in a memory leak as the original pointer would be overlayed by 'NULL'

Comment: these 'leaks' seem to be just all the allocations in the 'heap' and are not actually memory leaks

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, these are allocations, but they should not appear after when calling `_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince` with a recent memory check point. I suspect I have leaks because of the process growing memory usage.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm aware of the proper usage of temp pointer for storing `realloc` result. I just "fast fail" (report error and terminate) in case of `realloc` returning NULL (see my comment just below the realloc call), because *for the moment* my code can't deal with allocation failures, it just "fast fail".

Comment: Do you call `CompareMemory` twice? Though it seems to be valid, I would try to remove the first call.

Comment: @AlexFarber I get the same result if I don't `CompareMemory()` before stepping. Note that `CompareMemory()` is just a call to `_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince` so it should not have side effects.

Comment: @user3629249 I reworded "leaks" to "allocations" to avoid confusions. Also, the rest of the code is quite long, and I didn't manage to reproduce this in a small program :(

Comment: Any chance of multithreading issues? Also, is _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC defined? It may help to see a better leaks report.